# Upgraded to Entity Framework 6 Related entities not being inserted

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I upgraded From EF 4 to EF6 in my solution. Now my related entities are not getting inserted. How do I add records to the entity with foreign key relationship from the original enity

```
var _bp = new BP(); //BP is an entity 
 workflowList.ForEach(wf =>
 {
                var wflow = new Workflow
                {
                    currentstep = CustomConvert.ToIntNullable(wf.currentstep),
                    desc = wf.desc,
                    name = wf.name,
                    wfId = wf.id,
                    BP = _bp,
                    IsActive = true
                };
});

db.BP.AddObject(_bp);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The code above would add a record in BP table and add multiple records in the workflow table in EF 4 but in EF 6 it does not add any record to the Worflow table. How do I accomplish the same in EF6

Comment: Not sure how anyone will be able to help with no code, no error messages, no nothing.

Comment: Not clear what are you trying to achieve and what is your problem.

Comment: What is a `BP`?  What is `_project` and `_project.BPWorkflows`?

Comment: Do you expect the line `BP = _bp` to establish the relationship between `Workflow` and `BP`? Because I don't see anything else even remotely related to accomplishing what you want.

Comment: yes. BP = _bp did establish a relationship between workfow and BP in EF 4 but doesn't do that in EF6. I will have to add to the collection in EF6